# Counting MySQL duplicate rows using PHP returns error

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to do a count of the number of rows in a database and show me how many rows are in the database that contains duplicates.  However, I'm getting the following error:

`Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\wamp\www\SPARTAN-ver2\pages\scenario_card.php on line 203`

Here is the PHP I used

```
$countQuery = "SELECT breakers, COUNT(breakers) AS num FROM emergencies GROUP BY breakers";
$count = mysqli_query($db, $countQuery) or die(mysqli_error($db));
echo $count;
```

and here is what the SQL table headers look like

```
SYSTEMS         DESCRIPTIONS            BREAKERS
APU             APU Power Fail          APU [1]
APU             APU Starter Engaged     APU [7]
APU             APU Hot Start           APU [5]
AVIONICS        ADS 1 Fail              AVIONICS[1]
```

What does this error mean and what am I doing wrong?  Because when I run the query in PHPMyAdmin, I get the correct output which should be

```
BREAKERS        NUM
APU [1]         3
APU [5]         1
APU [7]         1
AVIONICS[1]     2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of "echo $count", try "var_dump($count)" .. then you will see, that you have an object, there - not a string or integer.

The error says, that you cannot convert that object to a string.

Use the property of the object, that contains the string (most likely result or something like that).

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query#refsect1-mysqli.query-returnvalues) of `mysqli_query`:

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
> EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a **[mysqli_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object**. For
> other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Once you have the return from `mysqli_query`, you can use the [`mysqli_fetch_*`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php#mysqli-result.synopsis) functions (such as [`mysqli_fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) or [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)) to retrieve the data itself.

Your final result will look something like:

```
$countQuery = "SELECT breakers, COUNT(breakers) AS num FROM emergencies GROUP BY breakers";
$rtn = mysqli_query($db, $countQuery) or die(mysqli_error($db));
$counts = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rtn);
echo $counts['breakers'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this:

```
$sqlCommand = "SELECT breakers, COUNT(breakers) AS num FROM emergencies GROUP BY breakers";
$query = mysqli_query($db, $sqlCommand) or die(mysqli_error($db));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
   print_r($row);
}
```

regarding http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

You can also use other implemented methods to fetch data from mysqli_query. mysqli_fetch_row(), mysqli_fetch_object(), mysqli_fetch_assoc()...